# Subsonic data set sort order

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, subsonic

I'm waaaay above my level of understanding here but have a simple request to change the sort order of data in a .NET datagrid.  The system seems to use SubSonic to do the database queries, so there's a level of abstraction which I just don't understand and can't seem to guess at ;).

There is a line under the gridview control in the .aspx file like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCsvReport" runat="server" SelectMethod="FetchAll" TypeName="WFlower.CsvReportController">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I've searched the project for 'CsvReportController' and there is a file in App_Code called 'CsvReportController.cs' in which there's a class like this:

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public CsvReportCollection FetchAll()
    {
        CsvReportCollection coll = new CsvReportCollection();
        Query qry = new Query(CsvReport.Schema);
        //qry.OrderDesc("CsvReportID");
        coll.LoadAndCloseReader(qry.ExecuteReader());
        return coll;
    }
```

Now, I've just no idea how to get this data to be sorted by the 'CsvReportID' field in descending order (currently it's ascending).

Can anyone shed any light on this.  Like I say, I'm in too deep here but it should be such a minor thing to do I'm determined to get to the bottom of it!

Thanks folks!

EDIT:
Okay, so as per @Mike Walsh's comment below, I tried this instead:

```
var qry = new Select().From(CsvReport.Schema); 
qry.OrderDesc(new [] {CsvReport.Columns.AssignedToID}); 
return qry.ExecuteAsCollection<CsvReportCollection>();
```

Now however, this throws a completely different error elsewhere:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__OrdersToDelete__245EFE8C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.OrdersToDelete'.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__OrdersToDelete__245EFE8C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.OrdersToDelete'.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error: 

Line 187:      //Do database management.
Line 188:      int removedUsers = SPs.Hg_DeleteInactiveUsers(14).Execute();
Line 189:      int removedOrders = SPs.Hg_DeleteInactiveOrders(14).Execute();
Line 190:    }
```

Comment: what version do you use ? looks like the 2.3

Comment: Can't remember the exact differences in 2.1-2.2-2.3 but will this compile for you?            
    var qry = new Select().From(CsvReport.Schema);
    qry.OrderDesc(new [] {CsvReport.Columns.AssignedToID});
    return qry.ExecuteAsCollection<CsvReportCollection>();

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've updated the main post with an error message thrown when doing this...

Comment: Well, you've solved your SubSonic problem but now you've got an SQL problem.  The SPs prefix is a hook into your standard SQL stored procedures so you'll have to look at what Hg_DeleteInactiveOrders actually does. A wild guess is there's a scheduled cleanup task, and you've run the delete SP twice before it ran. Workaround would be copy the query from the Delete SP into SSMS, change to a SELECT, see what it finds and delete the dupes from the OrdersToDelete table? I'll post my first comment as an answer. If the quick fix doesn't work post the second bit as a new question, it might be tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't remember the exact differences in 2.1-2.2-2.3 but will this compile for you?

```
    var qry = new Select().From(CsvReport.Schema); 
    qry.OrderDesc(new [] {CsvReport.Columns.AssignedToID}); 
    return qry.ExecuteAsCollection<CsvReportCollection>();
```